# How to use Google Gemini API call to upload pdf, ppt, docs, etc files?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, google-gemini, google-generativeai, gemini

I am using https://aistudio.google.com/ to use Google Gemini 1.0 to upload some pdfs, docs etc.

The documentation https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/generative-ai/docs/model-reference/gemini#request_body gives an example of the image but it doesn't work.

Can someone help me to tell me a way to upload files using an Gemini API to upload the files?

Comment: There are two Gemini APIs. The Vertex AI does support PDFs (inline or Cloud Storage). The Google Gemini API (which requires an API Key) does not support Cloud Storage (at this time). For the latter, there will be the Google Gemini File API, but that is in private preview at this time [REST API](https://ai.google.dev/api/rest/v1beta/files).